# Remove item from an array if it's value is equal to

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I have an array of numbers:

```
var myArray:Array = [12345, 23456, 34567, 45678];
```

If I want to remove say, `34567` is there a clean efficient way to do it?  I'm guessing I need to loop through the array, get the position of that value, then splice that position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Array.indexOf` to check on which index the value can be found in the array. If not found, it will be `-1`. In my example, I keep looping and removing until the index will be `-1`.

```
function removeFromArray(list:Array, value:*):void
{
    if (!list || !list.length) return;
    var index:int;
    while((index = list.indexOf(value)) > -1)
    {
         list.splice(index, 1);
    }
}

// test scenario

var myArray:Array = [12345, 23456, 34567, 45678, 34567];

trace("before:" + myArray);
//before:12345,23456,34567,45678,34567

removeFromArray(myArray, 34567);

trace("after:" + myArray);
//after:12345,23456,45678
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than one occurrence of 34567 you can filter array agains it by using [Array method filter()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#filter%28%29):

```
var myArray:Array = [12345, 23456, 34567, 45678, 34567]; // 34567

myArray = myArray.filter(
    function ( item : int, index : int, array : Array ) : Boolean {
        return ( item != 34567 ); // return true if item is not 34567
    }
)
```

Answer (score -2):

Hang on, just thought about this:

```
public function ArrayFinder() 
    {   
        var i:int =  (myArray.indexOf(34567));
        splice(i, 1);
    }
```

Comment: This could cause errors if the value cannot be found in the array. Always check if the index > -1. You cannot just call splice, it should be myArray.splice(). BTW ArrayFinder is a bad name for this function, and does not describe what happens.